java.lang.NullPointerException at okhttp3.ConnectionSpec.isCompatible when using custom SSLSocketFactory
I am trying to make Http calls from a Soap service deployed as a war file on Glassfish 5.1.0 in a remote windows server. At the point of making Http calls to other Microservices from the soap service, I get NullPointerException Issue. Currently I have upgraded the client (Okhttp) to version 3.12.13 and updated the code to use some TrustCertificates but I still get same issues. This is the stack trace of the error being returned :
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at okhttp3.ConnectionSpec.isCompatible(ConnectionSpec.java:207)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectionSpecSelector.configureSecureSocket(ConnectionSpecSelector.java:60)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:313)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:284)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:169)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:258)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:127)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:257)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:93)
    at com.tools.CallApi.banklyGetAuthToken(CallApi.java:172)
    at com.tools.CallApi.callBanklyRestApi(CallApi.java:278)
    at com.nibss.ObjNameEnquiry.process(ObjNameEnquiry.java:68)
    at com.bankly.nibss.NIPService.NameEnquiry(NIPService.java:187)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.util.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.util.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:77)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:34)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.InstanceResolver$1.invoke(InstanceResolver.java:220)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:119)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:58)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1106)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1020)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:989)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.run(Fiber.java:783)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.start(Fiber.java:390)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl.processAsync(WSEndpointImpl.java:338)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:368)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.metro.api.config.management.ManagedEndpoint.process(ManagedEndpoint.java:204)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.invokeAsync(HttpAdapter.java:704)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.invokeAsync(ServletAdapter.java:182)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doGet(WSServletDelegate.java:131)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doPost(WSServletDelegate.java:167)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet.doPost(WSServlet.java:51)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:665)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:611)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:550)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:75)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:114)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:332)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:199)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:439)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:515)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

This is my code:
public JSONObject GetAuthToken(String endPoint) {
    String rtn = "";
    OkHttpClient client = null;  // Could remain null if exception occurs
    JSONObject res = new JSONObject();  // Move this outside try block

    try {

        System.out.println("Making Authentication Call to Identity Server >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
        // Load the truststore
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(truststorePath)) {  // Use try-with-resources
            trustStore.load(fis, truststorePassword.toCharArray());
        }

        // Create TrustManagerFactory
        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);
        X509TrustManager trustManager = (X509TrustManager) trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers()[0];

        // Add ConnectionSpec with explicit TLS version
        ConnectionSpec spec = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)
                .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_2)
                .allEnabledCipherSuites()
                .build();

        client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(600000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .readTimeout(600000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(600000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .connectionSpecs(Arrays.asList(spec))  // Use single spec instead of MODERN_TLS, COMPATIBLE_TLS
                .sslSocketFactory(new CustomSSLSocketFactory(), trustManager)
                .build();


        System.out.println("client_secret before going out : " + client_secret);
        System.out.println("client_id before going out: " + client_id);
        System.out.println("grant_type before going out: " + grant_type);

        // Move the request creation and execution inside this try block
        String formargs = "client_secret=" + client_secret +
                "&client_id=" + client_id +
                "&grant_type=" + grant_type;

        MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, formargs);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(endPoint)
                .method("POST", body)
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                .build();
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        rtn = response.body().string();
        System.out.println("Raw Response Body: " + rtn);

        if (response.code() != 200) {
            throw new IOException("Server returned code: " + response.code() + " with body: " + rtn);
        }

        if (rtn == null || rtn.trim().isEmpty()) {
            throw new IOException("Empty response received from server");
        }

        try {
            res = new JSONObject(rtn);
            // Verify we got the token
            if (!res.has("access_token")) {
                throw new IOException("Response missing access_token: " + rtn);
            }
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            throw new IOException("Invalid JSON response: " + rtn, je);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        res = new JSONObject();
        res.put("error", "Auth failed: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    return res;
}

